# Angular - отправить данные POST для аунтификации

Tags: javascript, angularstrap, angularjs

Здравствуйте!
Надеюсь уже кто-то успел испробовать на практике этот чудо Angular фреймворк.
Сейчас вопрос в том, как правильно в Angular отправить данные POST(emamil, password).
Интересует структура HTML и сам контроллер Angular.

Мой код:

```
(function(){
    var App = angular.module('wm',[]);

    App.controller('login',function(){
        $scope.email = '';
        $scope.password = '';

        $scope.loginSubmit = function (){
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/registration/auth',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                data: JSON.stringify({email: $scope.email, password: $scope.password()})

            }).success(function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $scope.message = data.status;
            });
        }
    });
})();
```

Выкидываем море ошибок, одна из:

> $scope is not defined

Comment: App.controller('login',function(**$scope**){

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы после минимизации не попасть впросак, используйте `$inject`:

```
App.controller('login', LoginController);    
LoginController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function LoginController($scope){
  ...
}
```

, либо:

```
App.controller('login', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  ...
}]);
```

Первый вариант предпочтительнее.